# "son of fish knows how to swim" meaning and usage

Tags: translation

What the saying "son of fish knows how to swim" actually means? does it contain positive or negative connotation? Thank you!

Comment: I have never heard this idiomatic phrase before.  After conducting a quick Google search, I now know that this is translated from Portuguese.  I recommend that you check the [Portuguese Stack Exchange site.](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/)  Also, you can find the answer via Google.  I believe it means something along the lines of "like father, like son."

Comment: The acorn seldom falls far from the tree. It all depends on what you think of the tree.

Comment: related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/457206/origin-of-the-apple-doesn-t-fall-far-from-the-tree; https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97741/what-are-some-colloquial-english-phrases-for-a-child-acquiring-its-parents-cha

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out! It is exactly what I thought! However, the connotation is still unclear.. Is it OK to use it to compliment someone? Or rather opposite - to give an attitude? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user392938 I have never heard this phrase before either. After conducting a quick Google search, I have to say that it is certainly not an English idiom, and doesn't fulfil the requirement to be assigned the default sense of 'idiomatic' (widely accepted, used and understood).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are some colloquial English phrases for 'a child acquiring its parents' characteristics or features'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97741/what-are-some-colloquial-english-phrases-for-a-child-acquiring-its-parents-cha)

Answer (score 1):

It comes from a Portuguese saying:

> filho de um peixe pode nadar

It is not a familiar saying, but a near equivalent English saying might be something like

> Like father like son

Literally, the Portuguese means

> A fish’s son can swim

Comment: Thank you so much! It is exactly what I thought! However, the connotation is still unclear.. Is it OK to use this saying to compliment someone? Or  rather opposite - to give an attitude?? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nonna It depends entirely on the context.  I think that there is more scope negative context in the English than in the Portuguese version.  "Do you see David with that floozy at the table over there?  He's a married man!"  "Well, like father like son."  I do not know Portuguese well enough to know whether "Well, a fish knows how to swim" would fit that context.  It might only fit "Your son made me a fabulous bracelet" and positive things about what people  are able to do.